# Rails - I want to allow a user to change only their profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following tables: Users, Employees, Contacts.  Employee and Contact belongs_to User and User has_one Contact or has_one Employee. When a new Contact or Employee is created, I have their model create a new User.

I want the Contact (end user) to be able to edit their own contact record.  So, I have the following link:

```
<li><%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_contact_path(current_user.contact) %></li>
```

That brings up their record and they can edit it.  But, I don't want them to be able to retype the url with another contacts.id and edit their record.

I tried the following, but it doesn't stop them:

```
<% if current_user.contact = @contact %>
 <%= render 'form' %>
<% end %>
```

FYI - I also allow an admin person to edit the Contact records with this code:

```
<% if current_user.admin? %>
  <%= render 'form' %>
<% end %>
```

To explain further - the url looks like this:

```
http://localhost:5000/contacts/4/edit
```

And if you replace the 4 with a 6, it still brings up that record.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I really hope you meant `if current_user.contact == @contact`, with comparison, not assignment.

Comment: You can use a `before_filter` with a custom validation method that gets called before any contact edit page. That way, if the user tries to change the url, the custom validation method still gets called. Inside the custom method, you can check if `current_user == @contact`. If so, show the edit form, else redirect back and show an error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I think you might be missing a `=` sign.

```
<% if current_user.contact == @contact %>
 <%= render 'form' %>
<% end %>
```

Second, on `contacts#edit` action do something like

```
if current_user.contact != @contact
  flash[:error] = "you've been naughty"
 # also its recommended to record such an abuse attempt by logging or something
else
 # do rest here
end
```

You can also do more with something like [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) or another authorization gem (for instance, if you want to allow only specific users to edit a contact and not only `current_user`).

Answer (score 0):

Step #1
Create a method

```
def check_contact
if current_user.id != @contact.id
redirect_to root_path, alert: "Opps! you're not authorized to edit this "
end
end
```

Step #2
create a callback at the top of the controller that

```
before_action :check_contact, only: [:edit, :update]
```

Method #2
You may have some changes just in check_contact method like

```
 def check_contact
if current_user.contact != @contact
redirect_to root_path, alert: "Opps! you're not authorized to edit this "
end
end
```

then callback on top of the controller under controller name

```
before_action :check_contact, only: [:edit, :update]
```